# Embed environment variables in programmatic shell command execution

Tags: bash, shell, go

I am in a situation where I am trying to execute a shell command, but have its arguments be interpreted as environment variables properly.

For example, when I type the following into the terminal

```sh
ls $GOPATH
```

Bash interprets and expands the variable `$GOPATH`, and lists the contents of the `$GOPATH` directory. I am trying to do a similar thing with Golang's programmatic shell execution.

I have the following code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "$TESTVAR")

    cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(),
        "TESTVAR=this_is_a_test",
    )

    var outBuff bytes.Buffer
    var errBuff bytes.Buffer

    cmd.Stdout = &outBuff
    cmd.Stderr = &errBuff

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(outBuff.String()) // empty
    fmt.Println(errBuff.String()) // empty
}
```

This program outputs

```
$ go run test.go
$TESTVAR
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make the exec library interpret $TESTVAR as an environment variable as opposed to a string literal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help: [Go by Example: Environment Variables](https://gobyexample.com/environment-variables) and [Using environment variables in Go](https://flaviocopes.com/golang-environment-variables/)

Comment: `exec.Command` is not “programmatic shell execution“. If you want a shell, you need to execute a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "$TESTVAR")
```

with

```
cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "echo $TESTVAR")
```

Comment: This works, but is losing the safety one gets passing content argument-by-argument to `exec.Command()`; it's something one should only do in an environment where one trust one's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Bash and other shells interprets and expands variables, but the application is not executing Bash.

The application is executing the echo command.  The echo command, like most other commands, does not expand environment variables in its arguments.

You can either run Bash as shown in another answer or expand environment variables on your own.  Here's how to use [os.Expand](https://godoc.org/os#Expand) function to do this:

```
func newCommandEnv(env []string, cmd string, args ...string) *exec.Cmd {
    m := map[string]string{}
    for _, e := range env {
        if i := strings.Index(e, "="); i >= 0 {
            m[e[:i]] = e[i+1:]
        }
    }
    fn := func(placeholder string) string {
        return m[placeholder]
    }
    for i, a := range args {
        args[i] = os.Expand(a, fn)
    }
    fmt.Println(args)
    c := exec.Command(cmd, args...)
    c.Env = env
    return c
}
```